# Do civilian starships have blasters?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, weapon

I saw a question yesterday asking about civilian starships and shields, and that reminded me of another question I had. Is every starship supposed to have blasters, or some kind of weapon on them? Or do only certain ships have weapons?

Comment: Related; [Did the non-military Star Wars space ships have shields?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238260/did-the-non-military-star-wars-space-ships-have-shields)